# Understanding Low-Level Interface to Logs

Tags: documentation, keccak

This question is about [Low-Level Interface to Logs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#low-level-interface-to-logs), Solidity Documentation.

In given examples we are able to emit event normally:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ClientReceipt {
    event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint _value
    );

    function deposit(bytes32 _id) public payable {
        // Events are emitted using `emit`, followed by
        // the name of the event and the arguments
        // (if any) in parentheses. Any such invocation
        // (even deeply nested) can be detected from
        // the JavaScript API by filtering for `Deposit`.
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Or on a low-level:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract C {
    function f() public payable {
        bytes32 _id = 0x420042;
        log3(
            bytes32(msg.value),
            bytes32(0x50cb9fe53daa9737b786ab3646f04d0150dc50ef4e75f59509d83667ad5adb20),
            bytes32(msg.sender),
            _id
        );
    }
}
```

After the example there is this note:

> where the long hexadecimal number is equal to
>   `keccak256("Deposit(address,hash256,uint256)")`, the signature of the
>   event.

---

**Questions:** 
1) What is hash256? 
2) Why not bytes32? 
3) hash256 == bytes32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update: This was an error in documentation and it was fixed with [#3814](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3814) pull request.

---

I tried this algorithm in remix and it turnes out that the given note is misleading (at least for me).

Working example is `bytes32(keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)"))`.

So, answering question:
`hash256 == bytes32` is theoretically true, but
`hash256` != `bytes32` when you need to pass it as argument to `keccak256` function (yes, quite trivially, frankly speaking).

---

**Working example:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Demo {
    event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint256 _value
    );

    function highLevelEvent() public {
        bytes32 _id = 0x420042;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, 123);
    }

    function lowLevelEvent() public {
        bytes32 _id = 0x420042;
        log3(
            bytes32(123),
            bytes32(keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)")),
            bytes32(msg.sender),
            _id
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems an error in the documentation please report it to developers so they can fix it.

Comment: @Ismael done. [Issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3815) on github and [pull request](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3814) created.