# Solidity: Raise events via Assembly using log3

Tags: solidity, logs, assembly

I want to raise events from inside a piece of assembly code.

I've extended [the answer here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44628/understanding-low-level-interface-to-logs) with the function AssemblyEvent() which currently causes a runtime error.

---

**Working example:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Demo {
    event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint256 _value
    );

    function highLevelEvent() public {
        bytes32 _id = hex"420042";
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, 123);
    }

    function lowLevelEvent() public {
        bytes32 _id = hex"420042";
        log3(
            bytes32(uint256(123)),
            bytes32(keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)")),
            bytes32(uint256(uint160(msg.sender))),
            _id
        );
    }
    // ##########################
    // this function doesn't work
    // ##########################

    function AssemblyEvent() public {
        bytes32 _id = hex"420042";
        bytes32 t1 = bytes32(uint256(123));
        bytes32 t2 = bytes32(keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)"));
        bytes32 t3 = bytes32(uint256(uint160(msg.sender)));

        assembly {
            let s := 0x20
            let p := _id
            log3(p, s, t1, t2, t3)
        }
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong in the above code?  Also, as Assembly only has functions [up to log4](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/assembly.html), does this mean that 4 the maximum number of variables I can create logs for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What have I done wrong in the above code?

With inline assembly the `log3` function organizes the stack according to the given parameters and then executes the `LOG3` opcode. The stack inputs for an event, top to bottom, are as follows:

- memory location where the unindexed event data begins
- length of the unindexed event data within the memory
- indexed topic(s)

[Ethervm](https://www.ethervm.io/#A0) provides a good visualization of this.

In your example - by declaring `let p := _id` and then giving `p` as the top value in the stack when calling to `log3`, you are telling the EVM to obtain the unindexed data starting at location `420042`. This is well outside of the current memory size, and so the transaction fails from an invalid operation.

To achieve the desired results with minimal modification to the given example:

```
function AssemblyEvent() public {
    bytes32 _id = hex"420042";
    bytes32 t1 = bytes32(uint256(123));
    bytes32 t2 = bytes32(keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)"));
    bytes32 t3 = bytes32(uint256(uint160(msg.sender)));
    

    assembly {
        let p := add(msize, 0x20)
        mstore(p, t1)
        log3(p, 0x20, t2, t3, _id)
    }
}
```

In my example code I first assign `p` as a memory pointer that is 32 bytes beyond the size of the existing memory, so that I will not overwrite any existing data. I then store `t1` at that location. Finally I call `log3` with the memory pointer, a length of 32 bytes, and the sequence of indexed topics.

### Also, as Assembly only has functions up to log4, does this mean that 4 the maximum number of variables I can create logs for?

Four is the maximum number of **indexed topics** that you can return in an event. The first topic is the hash of the inputs, used to identify the event. You may additionally index up to 3 values within the event.

From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/contracts.html#events):

> You can add the attribute indexed to up to three parameters which adds them to a special data structure known as “topics” instead of the data part of the log. If you use arrays (including string and bytes) as indexed arguments, its Keccak-256 hash is stored as a topic instead, this is because a topic can only hold a single word (32 bytes).
>
> All parameters without the indexed attribute are ABI-encoded into the data part of the log.
>
> Topics allow you to search for events, for example when filtering a sequence of blocks for certain events. You can also filter events by the address of the contract that emitted the event.