# It is possible to create events dynamically in already deployed Smart Contracts?

Tags: solidity, events

It is possible, in an already deployed Solidity Smart Contract, to create new events trough an existing function (something like `new Event`)?

I'm not talking about emitting new events, from an existing and previously defined `Event`, but **dynamically creating new independent Events**.

Comment: can you give an example contract(using your own invented syntax) to demo a use case?

Comment: No it's not, There's a reason why we call them Immutable.

Comment: Not a chance unless the already deployed smart contract is upgradeable. If it's not then there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably possible using inline assembly, check out this post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72821/66634.

log1-4 are the assembly opcodes to generate events. I've never tried it myself, but you can probably use these and some inline assembly to generate completely custom events on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, I will research that option.